# Filtering, mapping and sorting documents in aggregation pipeline

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have an aggregation pipeline, and I am being able to get the required details as needed but I need to sort values of key named `visits` in descending order and then cherry pick items in it.

```
                {
                    $match: {
                        mobile_number: "1234567890",
                    }
                },
                {
                    $lookup: {
                        from: "visitor_logs",
                        localField: "_id",
                        foreignField: "visitor_id",
                        as: "visits",
                    }
                },
                {
                    $project: {
                        _id: 0,
                        visitor_id: "$_id",
                        first_name: "$first_name",
                        last_name: "$last_name",
                        mobile_number: "$mobile_number",
                        visits: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: "$visits",
                                as: "visit",
                                cond: {
                                    $and: [
                                        {$gte: ["$$visit.in_time", "1610609615"]},
                                        {$lte: ["$$visit.in_time", "1610615328"]},
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                        },
                    }
                },
            ]);
```

**Sample response**

```
{
    "type": "SUCCESS",
    "log": [
        {
            "visitor_id": "5ffff1354351be2c600c4f94",
            "first_name": "Ayan",
            "last_name": "Dey",
            "mobile_number": "1234567890",
            "visits": [
                {
                    "_id": "5ffff3df82dc1a0e90d89a5c",
                    "in_time": "1610609615",
                    "out_time": "1610609671",
                    "checked_in_status": false,
                    "visitor_id": "5ffff1354351be2c600c4f94",
                    "visit_purpose": "Test",
                    "person_to_meet": "Someone new",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ffff41a82dc1a0e90d89a5d",
                    "in_time": "1610609615",
                    "out_time": "1610609730",
                    "checked_in_status": false,
                    "visitor_id": "5ffff1354351be2c600c4f94",
                    "visit_purpose": "Test",
                    "person_to_meet": "Someone new",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5ffff45a82dc1a0e90d89a5e",
                    "in_time": "1610609615",
                    "out_time": "1610609919",
                    "checked_in_status": false,
                    "visitor_id": "5ffff1354351be2c600c4f94",
                    "visit_purpose": "Test",
                    "person_to_meet": "Someone new",
                    "__v": 0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, what I am looking for is to arrange the `visits` field in descending order based on `_id`. And by cherry-picking I mean, selecting only certain items inside `visits`.

Comment: Can you show us some documents and what are the fields part of each array element under `visits` and explain cherry picking?

Comment: @Gibbs Updated my question. Could you explain the reason of downvote?

Comment: try lookup with pipeline and add 2 stages first $match and second is $sort.

Comment: @turivishal yes I have done it that way(See comment in the answer). It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you have resolved, for the reference this may help you, try [lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `let` to pass localfield, pipeline to put your conditions in `$match` stage and your filter conditions you don't need to filter in `$project` stage. and put sort
  by `_id` in descending order

```
  { $match: { mobile_number: "1234567890", } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "visitor_logs",
      let: { visitor_id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $eq: ["$$visitor_id", "$visitor_id"] },
            in_time: {
              $gte: "1610609615",
              $lte: "1610615328"
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { _id: -1 } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            v_id: "$_id",
            in_time: 1,
            out_time: 1,
            checked_in_status: 1,
            visit_purpose: 1,
            person_to_meet: 1
          }  
        }
      ],
      as: "visits"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      visitor_id: "$_id",
      first_name: 1,
      last_name: 1,
      mobile_number: 1,
      visits: 1
    }
  }
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of sort does it use when combine with lookup.

Comment: *visits field in descending order based on _id. And by cherry-picking I mean* as per this i think he wants to sort lookup result in descending order.

Comment: @turivishal, this is perfect! I was using project to do the greater than , less than conditions. This snippet simplified things. Just one more thing, how do I cherry pick items inside visit array. Currently it has __v, visitor_id inside it which I want to remove and also rename the _id inside to something else.

Comment: you can do same you have did in root level $project stage, see updated answer.

Comment: @turivishal I asked about insertion/selection/any kind of sorts.

Comment: @Gibbs it will return in natural order as that placed in collection. but we should not depends on that, because the filtering and $match stage and other stages may unorder that documents in its pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is using `unwind` - [play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/llsjEVehovo)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {//de-normalize
    "$unwind": "$log"
  },
  {//de-normalize
    "$unwind": "$log.visits"
  },
  {//sort
    "$sort": {
      "log.visits._id": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Then you can add `$match` or `$project` based on your cherry-picking logic.

After cherry picking, you can reshape the data as the format in the question baby using `$group`

You can group again as sampled [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mty8jtL-gI1)

```
 {
    $group: {
      _id: "$categoryData._id",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      total_price: {
        $sum: "$asset_price"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Well, I tried this way but it just breaks the shape of the response. I would like to have it in the present structure but sorted and cherry picked. I could use map for the cherry picking but can't figure out how.

Comment: Well the structure is correct, but the sample response I showed you is after matching and then filtering. So basically, its a query for a search where, I need to put in a mobile number and have a date range as parameters. The response would then turn up like I showed and the visits array should be in descending order.

Comment: Ok! I figured it out. Sorted the array using pipeline in lookup stage.